# Is "platonic" generally appropriate?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, word-usage, politeness

Specifically, I'm wondering about the definition about relationships:

> of, relating to, or having a close relationship in which there is no romance or sex.

Is "platonic" generally appropriate?

It seems useful to describe non-romantic relationships, but most definitions emphasize the nonsexual part of the definition. Would it be appropriate to use in places where nonsexual would not be?

Comment: Yes, as in non-romantic. When you're flirting with someone, for example, that's neither Platonic nor necessarily sexual. Do you have a specific context in mind?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.  It is always a polite term for people who are not in a romantic relationship, but have a relationship that goes beyond mere acquaintance.

To my ear, it does not conjure any specific connotation of sexuality.  Rather, it speaks about their relationship being non-romantic in nature.

It can be applied to heterosexual and homosexual relationships alike.

You would not use it for a case of a sexual relationship without romance.  And, likewise, you would not use it to describe a romantic relationship without sex.  (*e.g.* two 12 year-olds who are dating, but not having an actual sexual relationship.)